# Duplicate source.list entry for Chrome

Tags: apt, google-chrome, source

When ever i am updating using `apt-get update` or via Synaptic, there will be some errors.
Can any one help me to solve the issue? I Google about it a lot, but didn't succeed. 
Errors are given below:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Comment: Please mention if you have any problem in updating Chrome or does it update successfully despite the error? Also, did you at any time edit your /etc/apt/sources.list? Just wondering why you see this error.

Comment: please give us the output of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list.d` specifically any parts that mention google or chrome.

Comment: Looks like a dublicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/13863/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicated-sources-list-entries